# DAX AVERAGEX including a 0 for total average

Tags: powerbi, dax

My table represents users working on a production line. Each row in the table provides the number of units a user produced within a 15 minute window. I am trying to calculate Units/Hour per User (which seems to be working fine), but my overall Average seems to be off.

Table and results of my measure:

[image]

Row by row it is what I am looking for. But the total average of 179.67 is wrong. It should be 196. I think for the 11:30 timestamp, Leondro did not have any work, and it is including a 0 for him. I would like to exclude that.

Measure:

```
UPH = 
var unitshour = CALCULATE(SUM(Table1[Units]) / (DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[DateTime])/4))
var users = AVERAGEX( VALUES(Table1[DateTime]), DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Username]))
RETURN

unitshour/ users
```

Comment: Why do you expect 196? The 179.67 looks right to me.

Comment: @AlexisOlson 196 is the average of the UPH column (if you average the numbers shown in the image). I am assuming the AVERAGEX is seeing that Leondro has nothing for 11:30, so it is giving me a zero for him at that time, reducing the average UPH from 196 to 179.67. I think I understand why that is happening, but I don't know how to get around it (exclude Leondro's UPH (which would be 0) at 11:30 because he did not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think 196 is the number you want if you want to treat each time period equally. I'd suggest this alternative:

```
UPH =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Table1[DateTime] ),
    CALCULATE ( 4 * SUM ( Table1[Units] ) / DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Username] ) )
)
```

If you want each time period to be weighted by the number of users in that time period, then the 196 it what you want.

```
UPHUserWeighted =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Table1,
        Table1[DateTime],
        Table1[Username],
        "UPH", 4 * SUM ( Table1[Units] ) / DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table1[Username] )
    )
RETURN AVERAGEX ( Summary, [UPH] )
```